# Strictly prohibit the use of Firefox browser, including a portable version using GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to using Windows Server 2012 R2 and i would like to know how to prohibit the user of Firefox browser, including a portable version using GPO. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.SE! If you consider your question answered, you can click the checkmark at the left of the specific answer which work on your problem.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs) should help you :

1. Run `gpedit.msc` to open Group Policy Editor
2. Expand `User Configuration` > `Administrative Templates`
3. Select `System`
4. Open the policy from the right panel: `Don't run specified Windows applications`

[image]

5. Set the policy to `Enabled`, then click `Show`

[image]

6. Add the programs you would like to prevent: `firefox.exe`

Comment: What will happen if I rename firefox to `fox.exe` for example?

Comment: It will not block the application. As such you want to use [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759075.aspx) and use `Publisher` rule or `File Hash` rule. I only mention the Group Policy method because it's the one on our question. You may edit it, and I will be more than happy to include how to use the AppLocker method.

Comment: @Vylix I am having an issue on https://superuser.com/q/1222878/742284