# How to delegate local administration of the client to a help desk group (without it having admin rights of the domain)

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to delegate local administration of the clients to a help desk group (without it having admin rights of the domain). How do i achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do does not make sense.  How can you delegate local administration of a client without giving that user group the same rights as the Administrator user group?  What would the point of giving a user local Administrator rights, when user is a domain user, local Administrator is virtually pointless (and powerless) in a case like that.

Comment: @Ramhound I don`t know whether i did it right but i created a group HelpDesk, then i added users to it. Then i created a GPO and i added HelpDesk to the Restricted Group under Security Settings.Finally i added it to the group Administrators. Is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: So you duplicated the Administrator user group.

Comment: @Ramhound i am not sure if i duplicated it but while doing the GPO of adding HelpDesk under Restricted Group, there was an option to add it under Administrators Group. I am ab bit confused but i followed this tutorial: http://pbarth.fr/node/78. Sorry it is in french.